# Dropdown with a form inside with twitter-bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a Dropdown in my TopBar, built with the Twitter Bootstrap CSS framework.

I have 3 problems with it that I can't find any solution to:

1. The text and password input fields are far too big, how can I adjust them? Making the dropdown box bigger would be OK too.
2. The labels for the fields are too dark, how can I lighten them up a bit?
3. The Dropdown is closing when I click into one of the fields. I have to reopen it and then I can type until clicking in the next field. The values are preserved even when the dropdown is closed. How can I make it stay open?

Here is a screenshot of problems 1 and 2:

[image: Screenshot of my problems 1 and 2]

Also here is the HTML for the TopBar as it is now.

```
<div class='topbar-wrapper'>
  <div class='topbar'>
    <div class='topbar-inner'>
      <div class='container'>
        <h3>
          <a href="/">Webworld</a>
        </h3>
        <ul class='nav'>
          <li>FILLER...</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class='nav secondary-nav'>
          <li class='dropdown' data-dropdown='dropdown'>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">Login</a>
            <div class='dropdown-menu' id='signin-dropdown'>
              <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/sessions" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="4L/A2ZMYkhTD3IiNDMTuB/fhPRvyCNGEsaZocUUpw40=" /></div>
                <fieldset class='textbox'>
                  <label id='js-username'>
                    <span>Username</span>
                    <input autocomplete="on" id="username" name="username" type="text" />
                  </label>
                  <label id='password'>
                    <span>Passwort</span>
                    <input id="userpassword" name="userpassword" type="password" />
                  </label>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class='subchk'>
                  <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Log In" />
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There hidden input is needed by rails and autogenerated.

I've  already tried to copy the implementation of the login form that twitter uses, but when I tried that, the TopBar is about 250px in height and the content of the dropdown is open, not closeable.

I have no custom CSS or JavaScript so far, except for the top-padding of 40px in the body as suggested by the bootstrap docs.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Try adding the code below somewhere in your javascript.  It should stop it from happening.

```
  $('.dropdown-menu').find('form').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Comment: Perfect, worked for me too - however, I think you are missing `);` to proper end the definition of the function to execute when the `click`  event is triggered :)

Comment: This is no longer valid, refer to kajo's answer

Answer (score 8):

(Twitter Bootstrap 2.x)

You may want to move the contents of `style=""` to your stylesheets...

If user entered wrong password:

add class `open` to `li class="dropdown open"`

and class `error` to `fieldset class="control-group error"`

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Login <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <form action="" id="form_login" style="margin: 0; padding: 3px 15px" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
        <fieldset class="control-group">
          <label for="form_email" class="control-label">Email address</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend" style="white-space: nowrap">
              <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
              <input type="email" name="email" id="form_email" autocomplete="on" class="span2">
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="control-group">
          <label for="form_password" class="control-label">Password</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-prepend" style="white-space: nowrap">
              <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
              <input type="password" name="password" id="form_password" class="span2">
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="true"> Remember me
        </label>
        <p class="navbar-text">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        </p>
      </form>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You don't need any extra css or javascript to make this look nice (with TB2.x)

Answer (score 7):

In case you don't want to stop propagation of your events, or that solution didn't work for you, you can add this code somewhere near initialization of bootstrap-dropdown:

```js
$('html').off('click.dropdown.data-api');
$('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api', function(e) {
  if(!$(e.target).parents().is('.dropdown-menu form')) {
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('open');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

For your third question - In your bootstrap-dropdown.js comment source code row

```
$('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
```

and write there this:

```
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (!$clicked.hasClass("dropdown-menu") &&
            !$clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown-menu")){
        clearMenus();
    }
});
```

Comment: Having the same problem as this user but these solutions are not working:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306433/twitter-bootstrap-cant-stop-a-dropdown-from-closing-on-click 

Decided to open up a separate question rather than this old one in case the issue is different for newer builds.

Comment: if you don't want to modify an externally maintained plugin, @crimefighter's [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10131791/1037948) can accomplish the same thing

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/bootstrap.css#L1559

max-width is set to 220px, remove the attribute and it will stretch itself.

Comment: This is really solution for problem 1 and works much better than the solution mentioned by marimaf, but problem 3 remains unresolved :( And especially #3 is the most annoying.

Comment: If you add the selector for this max-width attribute it would make the answer more clear since the link you added is dead.

Answer (score 2):

Its looks like a CSS based problem u are facing.

I fixed it with the following styles:

```
#signin-dropdown {
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 1em;
}
#signin-dropdown form {
    margin:0px;
}
#signin-dropdown form .textbox {
    margin-bottom:0em;
    padding-top:0em;
}

#signin-dropdown form .subchk {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 8px;
}

#username, #password, #userpassword {
    color: #404040;
    float: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-align: left !important;
    width: 140px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

About your questions 1 and 2.

1. Have you tried setting the length of the input? You can do this by setting the "size" attribute of the input tag. You can [read more here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp)
2. Did you try changing the style of the label? For example:

> ```
> <span style="color:#FFFFFF">Username </span>
> ```

Comment: OK, defining the styles inline :D Im curious why I have not seen that myself :) But the problem with the closing box remains.

Answer (score 0):

you just add your content in `<form></form>` tag

like this:

```html
 <div class="dropdown  dropdown-scroll" id="selectedClient">
    <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
        انتخاب <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu " role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>
        <form>
            <ul>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <input id="searchSubClientInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="جستجو بر اساس نام خانوادگی" ng-model="query">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
  <ul class="select-list scrollable-menu">
   <li class="dropdown-header">خودم</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```