# Bootstrap dropdown propagation closing when clicked

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, authentication

I am having an issue similar to this ([Bootstrap dropdown closing when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863821/bootstrap-dropdown-closing-when-clicked)), and I have tried the suggestions as listed, but the dropdown still closes when it is clicked on. The goal is to not have the dropdown close when you go to enter information in the input fields.

http://test.pf-db.com:3000/# (See 'Sign In' at upper right)

I have tried placing this code in the head, at the beginning of the body, and at the end.

```
    <script>
        $('.dropdown').dropdown().on("hide.bs.dropdown", function(e) {
            if ($.contains(dropdown, e.target)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            //or return false;
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I have also tried this

```
    <script>
    $('.dropdown').dropdown().on("hide.bs.dropdown", function(e) {
        if ($.contains(dropdown, e.target)) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        //or return false;
        }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: What are your trying to achieve? Please explain more.

Comment: You need `stopPropagation`, not `preventDefault`.

Comment: Where is the dropdown in your website??

Comment: Upper right: Sign In.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dropdown with a form inside with twitter-bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110356/dropdown-with-a-form-inside-with-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/fuLc4z3f/1/

Comment: why wouldn't you use the code in the answer you linked to?

Comment: I did use the code, as stated, but the Sign In dropdown is still closing when you click anywhere within the Sign In dropdown.

Comment: Use a Popover instead of a Dropdown!